# How to get field's data type name

Tags: database, vb.net

I am coding in vb.net, I get field information with GetSchema() from database, I find there is data_type property in result object, but has no Type_Name property. Anyone knows how to get Type_Name,  Or how to convert DATA_TYPE to Type_Name? for example , if data type equals 129 , it's name should be string .Thanks a lot, the simplified code like this:

```vb
Dim Conn As new OledbDbConnection

Dim Fields As New DataTable

Fields=conn.GetSchema("Columns", FilterValues)

For Each row As DataRow In Fields.Rows

    debug.? row("COLUMN_NAME") & row("DATA_TYPE")   'here I can read Column's name and data_type, but has no Type_Name

next
```

Answer (score 1):

Those numbers correspond to values in the `OleDbType` enumeration.

```vb
Dim table = connection.GetSchema("Columns")

table.Columns.Add("TYPE_NAME", GetType(String))

For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    row("TYPE_NAME") = CType(CInt(row("DATA_TYPE")), OleDbType)
Next
```

If you want to map them to .NET types then you'll need to do that manually. The documentation for the enumeration tells you which .NET type each OLE DB type maps to so you can create a `Dictionary` for the mapping.